# Grøstl MixBytes Python implementation

Tags: hash, finite-field, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to find an efficient way to implement the Grøstl matrix multiplication on python3.

So far I have managed to get this result :

```
    # M2 = GF(2^8) * 2 multiplication table
    # for each column i : 

    s0 = state[(i<<3) + 0]
    s1 = state[(i<<3) + 1]
    s2 = state[(i<<3) + 2]
    s3 = state[(i<<3) + 3]
    s4 = state[(i<<3) + 4]
    s5 = state[(i<<3) + 5]
    s6 = state[(i<<3) + 6]
    s7 = state[(i<<3) + 7]

    h = s7 ^ s6 ^ s5 ^ s4 ^ s3 ^ s2 ^ s1 ^ s0
    xh = M2[h] ^ h

    state[(i<<3) + 0] ^= M2[M2[s7 ^ s6 ^ s4 ^ s3] ^ s6 ^ s4 ^ s3] ^ xh ^ s1 ^ s3 
    state[(i<<3) + 1] ^= M2[M2[s0 ^ s7 ^ s5 ^ s4] ^ s7 ^ s5 ^ s4] ^ xh ^ s2 ^ s4 
    state[(i<<3) + 2] ^= M2[M2[s1 ^ s0 ^ s6 ^ s5] ^ s0 ^ s6 ^ s5] ^ xh ^ s3 ^ s5 
    state[(i<<3) + 3] ^= M2[M2[s2 ^ s1 ^ s7 ^ s6] ^ s1 ^ s7 ^ s6] ^ xh ^ s4 ^ s6 
    state[(i<<3) + 4] ^= M2[M2[s3 ^ s2 ^ s0 ^ s7] ^ s2 ^ s0 ^ s7] ^ xh ^ s5 ^ s7 
    state[(i<<3) + 5] ^= M2[M2[s4 ^ s3 ^ s1 ^ s0] ^ s3 ^ s1 ^ s0] ^ xh ^ s6 ^ s0 
    state[(i<<3) + 6] ^= M2[M2[s5 ^ s4 ^ s2 ^ s1] ^ s4 ^ s2 ^ s1] ^ xh ^ s7 ^ s1 
    state[(i<<3) + 7] ^= M2[M2[s6 ^ s5 ^ s3 ^ s2] ^ s5 ^ s3 ^ s2] ^ xh ^ s0 ^ s2
```

It works perfectly fine, however I was wondering if there would be a better way to do it, like by doing more intermediate precomputation, and without using more than one lookup table.

Comment: How much does "python3" really factor into the equation? In other words, are you really looking for some programming language specific thing (which may be considered off-topic on this site) or are you looking for something more general purpose?

Comment: I'm really looking to do it in python3, but I guess it is more about shortcuts that would be given by maths in GF(2^8) and could be applied elsewhere.